# cplex Python sum constraint

Tags: python, constraints, cplex

I just get started with cplex Python API and I got problem with creating `linear_constraints` for my model.

I want to do something like that:

```
dvar float+ x[]

Minimize:  Sum(i in I) C[i] * x[i]

subject to:
sum(i in I) x[i] <= constantValue
```

And my problem is that I don't know how to make constraint in Python API

```
  cpx.linear_constraints.add(
            lin_expr=  1,
            senses=["L"],
            rhs=constantValue,
            range_values= 2,
```

What do I need to type in 1) and 2) to get SUM of `x[i]` table which also need to be a decision variable?

Comment: I'd recommend that you take a look at the example scripts that are shipped with CPLEX (e.g., lpex1.py, etc.).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an example:

```
>>> import cplex
>>> c = cplex.Cplex()
>>> c.variables.add(names = ["x1", "x2", "x3"])
>>> c.linear_constraints.add(lin_expr = [cplex.SparsePair(ind = ["x1", "x3"], val = [1.0, -1.0]),
                                 cplex.SparsePair(ind = ["x1", "x2"], val = [1.0, 1.0]),
                                 cplex.SparsePair(ind = ["x1", "x2", "x3"], val = [-1.0] * 3),
                                 cplex.SparsePair(ind = ["x2", "x3"], val = [10.0, -2.0])],
                         senses = ["E", "L", "G", "R"],
                         rhs = [0.0, 1.0, -1.0, 2.0],
                         range_values = [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -10.0],
                         names = ["c0", "c1", "c2", "c3"],)
>>> c.linear_constraints.get_rhs()
[0.0, 1.0, -1.0, 2.0]
```

where range_values is a list of floats, specifying the difference between lefthand side and righthand side of each linear constraint. If range_values[i] > 0 (zero) then the constraint i is defined as rhs[i] <= rhs[i] + range_values[i]. If range_values[i] < 0 (zero) then constraint i is defined as rhs[i] + range_value[i] <= a*x <= rhs[i]. I would suggest to leave it to default value (blank).

To define a sum just indicate all variables and vector of ones, e.g.,

```
NumCols = 10
vars = [ 'x'+str(n) for n in xrange(1,NumCols+1) ]
coef = [1]*NumCols
cpx.linear_constraints.add(
        lin_expr= [cplex.SparsePair(ind = vars, val = coef)] ,
        senses=["L"],
        rhs=[constantValue] )
```

Comment: You might consider putting the second example at the top of your answer and simply say that the optional range_values argument can be omitted (it answers the question more directly).  The example at the top may be a bit overwhelming.  Also, it's worth noting that there is more than one way to do this.  You can use indices instead of names, lists of lists instead of using SparsePair's, etc.